# How to use GTK+ in Code::Blocks on Windows

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I wanted to use GTK+ in Windows Code::Blocks. I followed the instructions in [GTK+ Web](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows) and everything was successful except for one thing:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqm7Q.png)

I don't know where is GTK+ directory. I tried some directories but it gave me an error that location is not valid.

I just ignored it (I don't want to make this long so not explaining how I did it). Used `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` and GCC gave me an error: `fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory`

I tried `#include <gtk/gtk.h` but gave me an error: `fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: If you don't know where the directory is, just search your filesystem for `gtk.h`. Then move a few levels up and enter that folder in the dialog box you showed. That should solve that problem.

Comment: Is your question where _you_ installed GTK on _your_ computer? How should we know? Even if you don't know, how to track down an installation folder on your computer is quite fundamental "how to use computers" knowledge that you already ought to know before deciding to pick up programming.

Comment: @Lundin : Used defaults.

Comment: @Gerhardh still gives error. It says that path seems valid but wizard can't locate gtk.h

Comment: Do the installation once more but pay attention to where it put the folder? Or do a file search. Seriously, this isn't even programming, this is "how to use computers 101".